# "Summarizing over items, count the results and putting it on a bar chart"

Tags: powerbi, dax

For my challenge I need to count how many times a ship enters a port and how many time a ship leaves a port. I assign +1 each time he enters and -1 each time he leaves. If all movement get registered 100% accurate, the cummulated value can never be more than +1 (as a ship can not enter a port twice without leaving one in between :)) or less than -1 (for the same logica). As you can guess, it is not registered 100% accurate and I want to show how many ships deviate en by how much.

For this example I use the following data:

Ships: 
A, B and C

Ports:
X and Y

Registrations:

```
ID1 - Ship A enters X (+1)
ID2 - Ship A leaves X (-1)
ID3 - Ship A enters Y (+1)
ID4 - Ship B leaves Y (-1)
ID5 - Ship C leaves X (-1)
ID6 - Ship C enters Y (+1)
ID7 - Ship C leaves Y (-1)
```

The steps to take are:

Step 1: Cummulated for all ports:

```
Ship A = +1
Ship B = -1
Ship C = -1
```

Step 2: Value for histogram for all ports:

```
'+1' occurs 1 time
'-1' occurs 2 times
```

Step 3: Put these values onto a history of bar chart.

Or for only port X:

Step 1: Cummulated for port X:

```
Ship A = 0
Ship B = 0
Ship C = -1
```

Step 2: Value for histogram for port X:

```
'0' occurs 2 times
'-1' occurs 1 time
```

Step 3: Put these values onto the same history of bar chart.

The main challenge is that I need to be able to filter the results after the report is finished, so I cannot put everything into calculated tables or column because I lose the filter ability then. I am able to create a measure to do step one, but cannot put the result of that measure onto a histogram as Power BI does not know the 'context' of that measure. And I cannot give it context because that is done in the data model, which again will make me lose the filter ability. "

```
 CalcSumPerShip = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUMMARIZE(
            SHIP;
            SHIP[Ship];
            "SumPerShip";
            SUM(SHIP[Value])
        )
   )
```

This does not work because the result would be a vector and a measure output needs to be scalar. Any ideas how to make a bar chart from my data?

**Edit **

The data model is very simple:

[image]

The primary data is shown in this table:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your data model diagram?

Comment: I've added the model as well as a screen shot of the data in Power BI. It is a very simple model now, because all the complexity needs to be changeable for the user.

Comment: I'm still facing this problem. Whether I use measures, calculated columns or calculated table, I can't make the final step work. It is either a fixed solution on the whole dataset (or fixed subset), which makes it unavailable to slicing and filteren. Or it is a solution that is disconnected from the data model which makes it impossible to use in visualizations. Any thoughts out there?